# Calculating distance between two points in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So after spending a day, I finally got ruby geocoding installed and used it successfully in my rails.

I have a table called stop it contains fields : `id, name, address, longitude, latitude`.

The stop table has pre populated . I added some addresses of bus stops in the table and geocoding automatically added their respective longitude and latitude.

Now i have a small form

```
<%= form_tag("/welcome/index", method: "post") do %>
  <h5>Current Location</h5>
  <%= label_tag :address %><br> 
  <%= text_field_tag :address %>
 <p>
    <%= submit_tag("Submit") %>
  </p>


<% end %>
```

In this I capture the address entered by user in string format.

Then in my controller i convert it to longitude latitude as such

```
curAddress = params[:address]
@curlonglat = Geocoder.coordinates(curAddress)
```

So finally now i want to do a query in the Stop table and find the closest bus stop for the provided address. I was wondering what is the best way to do this? All answers are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `geokit-rails` https://github.com/geokit/geokit-rails

Add `acts_as_mappable` to `Stop` model and just use `Stop.closest(origin: [lat, lng])`

```
class Stop < ActiveRecord::Base
    acts_as_mappable defaults_units: :kms, lat_column_name: :latitude, lng_column_name: :longitude
    ...
```

Comment: This is very cool, so in Stop.closest(origin:[lat,lng]) -> This would be refering to the user entered longitude and latitude right?

Comment: in my case i have both longitude and latitude entered by user in one variable is it possible to jsut pass that variable ?if u look above u will see what i mean..

Comment: can i do this  Stop.closest(origin: @curlonglat)

Comment: if you can help me i would appreciate i am not getting correct bus stop

Comment: What's the format of @curlonglat? It should be an array of two floats, otherwise you can convert to it (e.g. `"1.3,100.3".split(',').map(&:to_f)`)

Comment: i just fixed it thanks again, i actually have another question i am just about to post it maybe you can help me answer it.